# Make carriage return (13) work when redirecting to a file

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have a little C program that plots a graph with ASCII characters.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 80; ++i) {
  if(i == val1)      { fputc('*', stdout); }
  else if(i == val2) { fputc('.', stdout); }
  else               { fputc(' ', stdout); }
}
```

Then I added some text into the graph.

```
printf("\rMy text");
```

This sets the cursor to the start of the line and overrides the start of the line with `My text`. This worked perfectly fine until I redirected the `stdout` of my program to a file.

```
./my-prog > graph.txt
```

This does not work because it's not `printf` that's interpreting the `\r` but the console(?).

Should I change my program to use a line buffer that can be overwritten or is there something else that can interpret the `\r`? Like this:

```
./my-prog | render > graph.txt
```

## Edit 1

`col -xb` does the trick:

```
./my-prog | col -xb > graph.txt
```

Comment: Please add more details about your use case to your question. Why do you want to write some text to a file and then overwrite it? Why not simply writing the second line of output without writing the first incomplete line? Please show a [mre] that uses `printf("\rMy text");` with the expected output in the file. With `cat graph.txt` you should get the same result on your terminal as with `./my_prog`.

Comment: I would suggest `line-buffer` for consistency across different environments.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The fist gave me an error `45617011: command not found` and the latter gave me exactly the same as calling it directly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, sorry it was a typo, but the result stays the same.

Comment: This one works: `./my-prog | col -xb > graph.out`

Comment: @mtraceur, sorry for the confusion and no no magic buffer. Pre-coffee comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's not `printf` that's interpreting the `\r` but the console

Yes, exactly. This cannot work on a regular file.

In order to overwrite text already written on a file, you will have to first use [`fseek()`](https://manned.org/fseek.3) to go back in the stream, and then re-write over what you already wrote. Furthermore, be careful, because `fseek()` will not work if you are writing to the console, so you will need to detect if you are writing to a console first, and then choose the correct output method. See also: [How to determine if a file descriptor is seekable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238788/3889449)

You could use [`isatty()`](https://manned.org/isatty.3) for this purpose:

```c
const bool stdout_is_tty = isatty(STDOUT_FILENO);

// Update this every time you begin writing a new line,
// you can either keep track of the number of written characters
// manually or use ftell().
long last_line_start = 0;

// ...

if (stdout_is_tty) {
    putchar('\r');
} else {
    fseek(stdout, last_line_start, SEEK_SET);
    // check return value of fseek for error (see manual)
}

printf("My text");
```

Comment: Can I use `fseek(stdout, 0, SEEK_END)`, to continue without loosing any dots after the text?

Comment: @Cosinus yes. Of course, you would have to be careful about where you `fseek()` and how much text you overwrite in order to have a reliable output, but you can definitely do that.

Comment: Does this mean that the file given in `./my-prog > file` is opened with `O_RDWR`?

Comment: @Cosinus no, usually when you do `./my-prog > file` the file is opened with `O_WRONLY`. In any case, seeking should work regardless of the open mode.