# How to determine if a file is seekable in Rust?

Tags: file, rust, file-descriptor, seek

In order to be able to infer a schema of a csv file passed via `/dev/stdin` before converting the whole csv file to parquet, I have implemented a wrapper that buffers the input and implements `Seek` as required by the crate `arrow2`. This all works.

This wrapper is, however, not necessary in certain situations like when a file is redirected to stdin: `my_binary /dev/stdin <test.csv`. I would like to only use that wrapper when it is really necessary, as in this case `zstdcat test.csv.zst | my_binary /dev/stdin`. As a result, I need to know whether the file I open errors on `seek` or not.

The following method I came up with seems to work. Is there a better way? Is this idiomatic for Rust?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open("/dev/stdin").unwrap();
    let seekable = match std::io::Seek::rewind(&mut file) {
        Ok(_) => true,
        Err(_) => false,
    };
    println!("File is seekable: {:?}", seekable);
}
```

There is a similar question for C, but the solution doesn't transfer blindly to Rust: [How to determine if a file descriptor is seekable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238788/how-to-determine-if-a-file-descriptor-is-seekable) - or is this effectively what `file.rewind()` does under the hood?

Comment: I would argue that if your program needs seekable access to a file, it should not be reading from standard input at all, or you should supply the name of the file from which the schema could be inferred as a separate argument to be opened internally (even if it ends up being the same file).

Comment: @chepner here's the use case where you do want to read from standard input: if you have a `zstd` compressed file that uncompressed would be 1TB, compressed only 10GB. You don't want to uncompress it to disk just so that the first 1000 lines or so can be read twice for schema inference.

Comment: Where does the seeking come in? Read the first 1000 lines, build the schema, then resume reading.

Comment: Crate `arrow-rs` expects Read and Seek to be implemented for `infer_file_schema`: https://docs.rs/arrow-csv/34.0.0/arrow_csv/reader/fn.infer_file_schema.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is a similar question for C, but the solution doesn't seem to transfer to Rust: How to determine if a file descriptor is seekable? - or is this effectively what file.rewind() does under the hood?

`rewind` actually performs a `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)`, so it'll have the side-effect of, well, rewinding (hence the name) the fd's cursor. I assume the reason the original uses `SEEK_CUR` is to avoid moving the cursor on seekable files for maximum generality.

If you want to match the original question exactly you should use `seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))`. If it doesn't matter then `rewind` is fine.

Additionally:

- you don't need a `match`, just call [`is_ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.is_ok) on the result of rewind (/ seek)
- you don't need to call `std::io::Seek::rewind(&mut file)`, if you `use std::io::Seek` then you can just call the provided methods on any seekable objects, like files

So:

```rust
use std::io::{Seek, SeekFrom::Current};

fn main() {
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open("/dev/stdin").unwrap();
    let seekable = file.seek(Current(0)).is_ok();
    println!("File is seekable: {:?}", seekable);
}
```

matches the C answer exactly.

Though for what it's worth on my mac the device files are seekable by default.

Only way I can get it to fail is if I pipe (*not redirect*):

```bash
> ./test
File is seekable: true
> </dev/null ./test
File is seekable: true
> </dev/null cat | ./test
File is seekable: false
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great advice. Yep, only when you pipe is it not seekable.